# Android application crashes after migrating unity 2019 -> 2021

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, migration

We're trying to update unity from version 2019 to 2021.
After update android application randomly crashes. Session time from 3 minutes till 40.
Also, there no steps to repo.

Tried to disable all SDKs, update to 2020 and 2022, change stripping code, change compilation from il2cpp to mono and lof of other variants but without any results.

It would be great to hear any ideas. Thx!

```
2022-11-22 17:46:35.813 6299-6411/com.***.*** E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: UnityMain
    Process: com.***.***, PID: 6299
    java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Version '2021.3.13f1 (9e7d58001ecf)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'mono', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
    Build fingerprint: 'samsung/m32xx/m32:12/SP1A.210812.016/M325FVXXS4BVJ1:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '3'
    ABI: 'arm'
    Timestamp: 2022-11-22 17:46:34+0200
    pid: 6299, tid: 6411, name: UnityMain  >>> com.***.*** <<<
    uid: 10762
    signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN), fault addr 0x97
        r0  0000008b  r1  00000097  r2  a6045de0  r3  00000002
        r4  0000008b  r5  00000000  r6  c4447440  r7  c23cf264
        r8  00000002  r9  a6045de0  r10 c23cf2a8  r11 00000000
        ip  bfc4f380  sp  c60d7870  lr  c6b6c093  pc  c6b70ba8
    
    backtrace:
          #00 pc 0032fba8  /data/app/~~-yOypRKW_zJrZZDfaDURbQ==/com.***.***-zHyjP_HS-QJKpSjVK2hWuQ==/lib/arm/libunity.so (EventManager::InvokeEventCommon(EventManager*, EventEntry*, void*, int)+26) (BuildId: 60691ac925aaa903ed9fa2d3edd0b108518d4dbd)
          #01 pc 0032b08f  /data/app/~~-yOypRKW_zJrZZDfaDURbQ==/com.***.***-zHyjP_HS-QJKpSjVK2hWuQ==/lib/arm/libunity.so (delete_object_internal_step1(Object*)+26) (BuildId: 60691ac925aaa903ed9fa2d3edd0b108518d4dbd)
          #02 pc 0032ac1d  /data/app/~~-yOypRKW_zJrZZDfaDURbQ==/com.***.***-zHyjP_HS-QJKpSjVK2hWuQ==/lib/arm/libunity.so (delete_object_internal(Object*)+8) (BuildId: 60691ac925aaa903ed9fa2d3edd0b108518d4dbd)
          #03 pc 005fba11  /data/app/~~-yOypRKW_zJrZZDfaDURbQ==/com.***.***-zHyjP_HS-QJKpSjVK2hWuQ==/lib/arm/libunity.so (DestroyObjectHighLevel(Object*, bool)+28) (BuildId: 60691ac925aaa903ed9fa2d3edd0b108518d4dbd)
          #04 pc 0058b211  /data/app/~~-yOypRKW_zJrZZDfaDURbQ==/com.***.***-zHyjP_HS-QJKpSjVK2hWuQ==/lib/arm/libunity.so (BackgroundJobQueue::ExecuteMainThreadJobs()+24) (BuildId: 60691ac925aaa903ed9fa2d3edd0b108518d4dbd)
          #05 pc 005ff843  /data/app/~~-yOypRKW_zJrZZDfaDURbQ==/com.***.***-zHyjP_HS-QJKpSjVK2hWuQ==/lib/arm/libunity.so (InitPlayerLoopCallbacks()::EarlyUpdateExecuteMainThreadJobsRegistrator::Forward()+30) (BuildId: 60691ac925aaa903ed9fa2d3edd0b108518d4dbd)
          #06 pc 00600c41  /data/app/~~-yOypRKW_zJrZZDfaDURbQ==/com.***.***-zHyjP_HS-QJKpSjVK2hWuQ==/lib/arm/libunity.so (ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*)+66) (BuildId: 60691ac925aaa903ed9fa2d3edd0b108518d4dbd)
          #07 pc 00600c81  /data/app/~~-yOypRKW_zJrZZDfaDURbQ==/com.***.***-zHyjP_HS-QJKpSjVK2hWuQ==/lib/arm/libunity.so (ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*)+130) (BuildId: 60691ac925aaa903ed9fa2d3edd0b108518d4dbd)
          #08 pc 00600e41  /data/app/~~-yOypRKW_zJrZZDfaDURbQ==/com.***.***-zHyjP_HS-QJKpSjVK2hWuQ==/lib/arm/libunity.so (PlayerLoop()+224) (BuildId: 60691ac925aaa903ed9fa2d3edd0b108518d4dbd)
          #09 pc 009a53f9  /data/app/~~-yOypRKW_zJrZZDfaDURbQ==/com.***.***-zHyjP_HS-QJKpSjVK2hWuQ==/lib/arm/libunity.so (UnityPlayerLoop()+576) (BuildId: 60691ac925aaa903ed9fa2d3edd0b108518d4dbd)
          #10 pc 009cdd9d  /data/app/~~-yOypRKW_zJrZZDfaDURbQ==/com.***.***-zHyjP_HS-QJKpSjVK2hWuQ==/lib/arm/libunity.so (nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+40) (BuildId: 60691ac925aaa903ed9fa2d3edd0b108518d4dbd)
          #11 pc 003af19d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_alloc_string_from_bytes_region_tlab_instrumented+44) (BuildId: 8a3405190074d955145af6042a9f3658)
    
        at libunity.EventManager::InvokeEventCommon(EventManager*, EventEntry*, void*, int)(InvokeEventCommon:26)
        at libunity.delete_object_internal_step1(Object*)(delete_object_internal_step1:26)
        at libunity.delete_object_internal(Object*)(delete_object_internal:8)
        at libunity.DestroyObjectHighLevel(Object*, bool)(DestroyObjectHighLevel:28)
        at libunity.BackgroundJobQueue::ExecuteMainThreadJobs()(ExecuteMainThreadJobs:24)
2022-11-22 17:46:35.814 6299-6411/com.***.*** E/AndroidRuntime:     at libunity.InitPlayerLoopCallbacks()::EarlyUpdateExecuteMainThreadJobsRegistrator::Forward()(InitPlayerLoopCallbacks:30)
        at libunity.ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*)(ExecutePlayerLoop:66)
        at libunity.ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*)(ExecutePlayerLoop:130)
        at libunity.PlayerLoop()(PlayerLoop:224)
        at libunity.UnityPlayerLoop()(UnityPlayerLoop:576)
        at libunity.nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)(nativeRender:40)
        at libart.art_quick_alloc_string_from_bytes_region_tlab_instrumented(art_quick_alloc_string_from_bytes_region_tlab_instrumented:44)
```

Comment: The content of java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** line would be very helpful... Can you share it...?

Comment: @DanBaruch I'll try to find a way to get this line. This line is provided by Android for debug builds.

Answer (score 0):

We face this issue also but on lower update: from 2021.3.9 to 2021.3.12. It was affecting 20% of our users on production.
According to logs, it is related to scene loading.
So looks like this issue started to appear somewhere after 2021.3.9.
Rolling back to this .9 version solved it for us.